# How to disable autofill with Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

There are several threads about this. However, it seems that many workarounds no longer work with the latest versions of Chrome (e.g. 41.0... at the time of this thread), and I couldn't find any up to date solution.

More, the pattern I'm struggling with make use of the `data-rel`attribute:

```
<input data-rel='city' type='text' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' spellcheck='false'/>
```

What would be your best ideas to get rid of this autofill?

Comment: Please check my workaround here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill/36030236#36030236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use autocomplete.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input data-rel='city' type='text' />
</form>
```